# How to use CQL_FILTER for the highest value in a layer field?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, cql-filter

I need to query/filter my wms in openlayers to only see the polygons classified with the highest values in a given field.

Would be something like:

```
wms_layer.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "ND = max(ND)"});
```

But this is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that. If you want to get the highest value of a filed you have to use WPS, GeoServer has a process that does basic statistics on fields, including the max value.

Comment: How do I do this?